# MS Access does not save some edited records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have Access 2010 dtb, B/E is located in the SharePoint library, F/E's are on local computers. Users can edit data from the forms only, which are unlocked by VBA code acc. to user's permissions. Sometimes occur strange dtb behaviour - the records are updated in the form but when I re-open this form, some of the edited records were not saved (they contained data before editation). I suspect interrupted internet connection to the sharepoint but I don't know how to check it. Or do you have any other idea what's happened?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: it could also be that your INSERT has an error like the types are not matching or a value does not meet restrictions of a field. for example you define a field "age" in your database with a constraint that it has to be between 0 and 100. if you try to insert a recordset to your db now with an age of 200, the operation will fail quietly

Comment: The simple text fileds were updated, there is no validation rule or other restrictions...

Comment: I found the very similar issue: [link](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html) . So I implemented the forced saving and I will see :-)

Comment: Hmmm, looks it did not help :-( I added data directly in the table (as administrator, users can't), it looks saved (data were displayed on the report) but the next day the data was not in the table. According to the primary key, which continued subsequently, it looks that the data was not saved anymore.